# How to get the files that I saved while using windows in other drives than C:?

Tags: usb, files, drive

I had some files in my windows OS, when I used it. I saved them in Drives D: & X:. Now, I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 in it. Where can I find those files?
I installed in C: by completely removing my windows 10.
And, if I connect a USB, how to find that in Ubuntu? I'm new in Ubuntu, so help me...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not clear. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/998085/edit) your question above and add more information about your system and what you are trying to do. When you installed Ubuntu, did you replace Windows with Ubuntu or did you install Ubuntu side-by-side Windows? If connect an USB it should show up in the *Files* (also known as Nautilus). Is `X:\` your USB?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu Along side Windows, or on whole disk ?

Answer (score 1):

Use The file browser, **Nautilus** or the GUI Disk app **Gnome-disks**.

In most cases the drives that are available will be shown in the File Browser.  The default file browser installed is **Nautilus**.

You'll see a list of drive devices on the left panel of Nautilus.  They'll usually be listed by the Volume size or the Partitiion Label, such as **Windows**, **OS**, **Data**, etc.

You'll also see a new device that will appear in that list if you insert a Pen drive or other media into the computer.

Just click the device to open it up and browse... much like browsing the drives in Windows File Explorer.

You can also browse the available attached drives and devices with the **Gnome-Disks** app.  You can get to it by typing `Disks` in the Ubuntu Search button.

In this GUI interface, you will see all the attached drives and partitions.  Click the one you want to browse.  It it's in a recognized formate you will see a **Play** button (a triangle) that will mount it.  Then you'll see a description at the bottom with a clickable link to the drive (ie `Contents Ext4(version 1.0) --Mounted at /media/ljames/OS1`).

You'll see all your drives and partitions that are available in this app.